# HERE Destination Weather API: Can I use lat/lon instead of name?

Tags: here-api

Using the documentation for the HERE Destination Weather API under https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/auto_weather I cannot find the information whether it is possiblen to use latitude and longitude instead of a City name for forecasts.

Does this option (using lat/lon instead of `name`) exist?

Comment: Please tell me if I understood it correctly, you want to use City name instead of latitude and longitude in your JSON, does that mean that you want to convert the latitude and longitude into name of location is it so ?

Comment: I do not understand why this is marked as off-topic. I have a question regarding an API documentation and @ctrlw did provide a spot on answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is linked on the page you shared:
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/auto_weather/weather-observation-lat-long

Example for current weather:
https://weather.cit.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=observation&latitude=52.516&longitude=13.389&oneobservation=true&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy

Example for weather alerts:
https://weather.cit.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=alerts&latitude=52.516&longitude=13.389&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy

Comment: Thank you. I was using looking at the examples for forecast which always use the `name` parameter. I was outright overlooking the second entry on the left menu.